# How to see installed Swing application console/log?

Tags: java, swing, windows-console

I have installed a Java Swing application at a user machine. Now I want see console/log when software will be run at that machine.

This application is working correctly at machine but is not working at user machine. So i want to debug this at user machine.

So Please suggest - how to see installed Java Swing application console/log like Eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

You can run your application from terminal, in this case all the log will be printed on terminal.

Also if you can use some logging library then it will be very helpful.

Comment: I think that by the time it comes to getting information from the user, a proper logging API should be used. They usually provide means for directing the logging output to different locations, including to a log file, and allow for easy changing of the level of detail provided.